# Automate GAS execution

Tags: google-apps-script

What are the different options to automate GAS execution?

As of now I run them manually and I have been looking around to automate them and have a quiet few .gs files that I run everyday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for Time-driven triggers.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers